# Trying to find the selector to change colour of Phone Number text in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm having a really tough time trying to override the styling in a Wordpress site. What I'm trying to do is make create a media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .phone-text {
     color: black;
     }
}
```

This is the actual text of the class, when I look in the development tools for Chrome. For some reason, when I enter this in the custom CSS portion of the site, it is not overriding the style of the template.

Update:

Received the advice to attempt the following:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
      #masthead .header-right-wrap .extract-element .phone-text 
      {
      color: black; 
      }
}
```

I get the logic of using a more specific selector, but this is not overriding the colour. It would appear to work in the developer tools, but perhaps there's something odd in Wordpress?

Comment: You need  more specific selector because this selector - `#masthead .header-right-wrap .extract-element .phone-text` seems to be setting the color to white.

Comment: have  you tried !important

Comment: I think in the parent div `.header-right-wrap` sets the white color

Comment: @Harry I'm still looking for what the selector would be, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what exactly it is.

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев Just tried it out, doesn't seem to override the default styling.

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harry is right in the comment above. 
CSS is all about specificity. Think about it this way:
If I walk into a room full of people and say, "Hey, guys!" all the guys turn around. If I walk into the same room and say, "Hey, Dave!" only the guys named Dave will respond. If I say "Hey, Dave Nelson!" chances are that will apply to only one guy. The more specific instruction "wins."

The browser compares your CSS applying to `.phone-text` with `#masthead .header-right-wrap .extract-element .phone-text` applying the same property. The more specific one wins; the color #fff is rendered. ".phone-text that is inside .extract-element that is inside .header-right-wrap that appears in #masthead" is much more specific than "anything called .phone-text".

If you moved .phone-text outside of that container cadence, your color would be applied. If you set a property that `#masthead .header-right-wrap .extract-element .phone-text` doesn't set - like a border - just `.phone-text` would do.

Comment: I've applied an update on the main post, as this isn't best place to show the code I'm typing.

Comment: On inspecting the element, it looks like the color: white is set on line 138 while the color: black is set on line 135. Order matters too - whoever gets the last rule in wins. So the "white" is overriding the "black" because it's later.

Comment: Strange, it seems to work when applying the style to a specific page, but not when trying to apply it in the templates "Custom CSS".

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect in what order those declarations are getting loaded. Depending on the order the stylesheets are loading, they may override one another.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can do from here, as I believe you've given me the selector to solve my problem. Thanks so much for your help.